# How to integrate CEPH with Amazon-S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, ceph

I'm trying to adapt the open-source project [mmfashion](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmfashion) on Amazon SageMaker that requires the [CEPH](https://ceph.io/) module for backend. Unfortunately `pip install ceph` doesn't work. The only work-around was to build the [ceph source-code](https://github.com/ceph/ceph) manually by running in my container:

```
!git clone git://github.com/ceph/ceph 
!git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This does allow me to import `ceph` successfully. But it throws the following error when it comes to fecthing data from Amazon S3:

```
AttributeError: module 'ceph' has no attribute 'S3Client'
```

Has someone integrated [CEPH](https://ceph.io/) with Amazon S3 Bucket or has suggestions in the same line on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ceph S3 api  to connect to  AWS buckets , here is the simple python  example script to connect to any S3 api :

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
access_key = 'put your access key here!'
secret_key = 'put your secret key here!'

conn = boto.connect_s3(
        aws_access_key_id = access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
        host = 'objects.dreamhost.com',
        #is_secure=False,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )
```

then you will be able to list the buckets :

```
for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets():
        print "{name}\t{created}".format(
                name = bucket.name,
                created = bucket.creation_date,
        )
```